# Приложение для раскраски картинок

Tags: android

Хочу попробовать написать небольшое приложение для раскраски картинок. Есть такая картинка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста с чего нужно начать? Как такие приложения пишут?

Answer (score 0):

Такое на `Canvas`, `Paint class`
или на библиотеках обёртках
[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas)

[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-create-a-paint-application-for-android-5b16968063f8)

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать